# C# TextWriter adds new line for no reason

Tags: c#, io, textreader, textwriter

Hello fellow StackOverflow users.

## The Problem

I have a simple C# code, where I have method that takes both an `TextReader` (reader) and an `TextWriter` (writer) as arguments.

Everytime I run `writer.Write("\n")` it jumpts **2** lines and `writer.Write(" ")` it adds an space and jumps **1** line. How can I prevent it from adding those new lines?

I am passing, respectively, `Console.In` and `Console.Out` as `reader` and `writer`.

## The Code

```
public Matriz(TextReader reader, TextWriter writer) {
    int rows, columns;
    decimal[,] _map;

    ... reading rows number and columns number ...

    _map = new decimal[rows, columns];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        writer.Write ("\n"); // adds 2 lines
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            writer.Write (""); // adds one line
            _map [i, j] = Convert.ToDecimal (reader.ReadLine ());
        }
    }

    this.map = _map;
}
```

Comment: According to this sample and also tested, there is no newline, only if you use WriteLine : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Insted of passing \n try passing Environment.NewLine.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);
```

This might fix your problem. If it doesn't let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## The Solution

Dumb me! The problem is actually `reader.ReadLine`. When it gets called, it reads and **adds** a new line.
Replacing it with `reader.Read` worked from me.

Comment: Glad your problem fixed